# Scroll to jQuery functions weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a jQuery smooth scroll script:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 500,'swing');
 });
```

It scrolls fine to

```
<a id="info"></a>
```

But doesn't work on any of my others

```
<a id="top"></a>
<a id="bottom"></a>
<a id="announcements"></a>
etc ...
```

When manually adding domain.com/#top it works, so the anchors should be fine.

Does anyone know why?

Live preview:
http://thehtmlworkshop.com/

Comment: Would you like to create fiddle for this issue?

Comment: It might depend on the position of the elements. Without more information it is impossible to say. Right now we only know that the `id`s of the elements are different but that alone won't make jQuery treat them differently.

Comment: I know that announcements and templates won't work as i didn't create the anchors but #top and #bottom are there and they don't work.

Comment: Apparently the elements are not there, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined `, although I can see them in the page source. Usually, `a` elements either link to a page and need an `href` attribute or are anchors and need a `name` attribute. Try changing from `id` to `name`.

Comment: Although my suggestion is still worth to be considered, the problem is that you attached the `scroll` class to the wrong elements. Add it to the links themselves, not the images inside of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons top and down has no class `scroll`. Try to add it.

```
<a href="top" class="scroll" /><!-- img --></a>
```

And then to be sure, that the `a` will fire event:

```
$("a.scroll").click(function(event){
    //your code there
});
```

Comment: Good catch. The problem is that the `img` element inside the links has the `scroll` class, not the link itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are settings the click to class of 'scroll'. The click event needs to be set to the parent.

```
$(".scroll").parent().click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 500,'swing');
});
```

Comment: This will break the `info` link though. The problem is not binding the event handler, it's the inconsistent assignment of the `scroll` class.

Comment: Right. All of the links on the page aren't coded consistently. After looking through the code a little more I alos noticed there aren't any elements with an id of 'templates' or 'announcements' which could also be causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsfiddle: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/tpressley1/bHMUC/31/).

The JQuery:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){

var target = $(this).hash;
 var dest=null;
 if(($(this.hash).offset().top) > ($(document).height()-$(window).height())){
      dest= $(document).height()-$(window).height();
 }else{
      dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
 }

$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000, 'swing');
 event.preventDefault();
```

});